Linux IRQ handler gets affected from user-space process
I wrote a Linux kernel module which receives data from a remote core through shared memory and passes it on to a user-space application. My driver is notified about new data via a mailbox interrupt triggered from the remote core.
When the application tries to read data and there is none available, the driver puts the process to sleep with wait_event_interruptible(). The IRQ handler then wakes it up with wake_up_interruptible().
I have noticed that my IRQ handler takes 1 microsecond if there is no process reading and 20 microseconds when there is a process reading. The only difference is one if-statement in my IRQ code, like if (someone is waiting) then wake_up_interruptible(), which either gets executed or not. Is it normal that the wakeup takes so long?
The weird effect happens when I start to overload the CPU (I did this to test the real-time capability of the reader application). When the load-test program, which from time to time occupies the CPU, is run with high enough priority, it does not just affect the reader process but also the IRQ! The IRQ - which should be triggered every millisecond - gets deferred several milliseconds and is "queued up" - they then all run shortly after another.
I would expect the following:

wake_up_interruptible() shouldn't take that long
the IRQ should not fall out of its 1ms pattern, even if the reader process gets preempted

How I analysed this:

My IRQ handler sets a GPIO to high when it starts and to low when it returns. A monitor the GPIO with an analyser.
I used the function in_interrupt() and an occasional printk() (every thousand interrupts) to check that I am truly inside IRQ context.

What could I be doing wrong?
-------------------- EDIT --------------------
Thanks to 0andriy's comment I found a solution, but I still do not understand why I see the above effect and I would be glad if someone could explain it to me.
My solution is simply to force the IRQ to run on a different core than the reader process. Like this, the time for the interrupt goes down to 3 - 4 microseconds, which seems reasonable to me. Furthermore, when I overload the reader process, it does not affect the interrupts any more.

Where are the interrupts "queued up"? Is there a queue of interrupt events pending delivery in the mailbox or remote core?

"I did this to test the real-time capability of the reader application" - Linux is NOT a real time OS. It provides real-time capabilities neither for applications nor for the kernel.

You CPU most likely gets enough time to decide to go to sleep. When you load CPU, you basically prevent it from sleeping (on Intel hardware it's called C-states). Try to disable PM QoS (you can do that via /proc/cpu_dma_latency). Also you may read this https://gist.github.com/wmealing/2dd2b543c4d3cff6cab7. And check IRQ affinity, it can be that your IRQ handler is being handled by another (idling) CPU core.
